# Jquery Ajax data not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

In the following ajax request, I am sending a request to my node server to do some work on the file with name `fileName`.

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {'imageFileName': fileName},
    contentType: "json",
    url: '/myRoute',
    success: function(data){
        if(!data){
            errorMessage();
        }
        else{
            display(data);
        }
    }
})
```

Router

```
router.post('/myRoute', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.imageFileName) //Undefined
    res.end();
})
```

However, when I log the request on the server-side, I get a giant object without the `fileName`. Given that the request is named `req`, `req.imageFileName` yields undefined. What am I doing wrong such that I can't access `fileName` on the server side?

Comment: Are you trying to send the file or just the filename?

Comment: I think `contentType` should be `application/json` and not just `json`, it's a MIME type.

Comment: Posting the relevant part(s) of your server side code would be helpful.

Comment: Added the code. Changing it to `application/json` causes a 400 error for some reason.

Comment: Does `res.end()` return the res as data into success?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing quote in data. Also cross check oncec what is in the filename.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {imageFileName: fileName},
    contentType: "json",
    url: '/myRoute',
    success: function(data){
        if(!data){
            errorMessage();
        }
        else{
            display(data);
        }
    }
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The quotes do not make a difference and the name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {'imageFileName': fileName},
url: '/myRoute',
success: function(data){
    if(!data){
        errorMessage();
    }
    else{
        display(data);
    }
}
})
```

server side

```
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: false
 }))
```

I want to see if its the content type thats giving you trouble.

Comment: I have `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());` in my app.js.

Comment: Nope doesn't work, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can you try this instead? I want to see if it's the content-type that's giving you trouble

Answer (score 0):

The tag is in the `body` of the request, as provided by body-parser. Therefore, this worked.

```
router.post('/myRoute', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.imageFileName) //Correct
    res.end();
})
```